# Selenium - what is the difference between click and clickAndWait?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to selenium and need some clarification on some stuff. I've tried `click` and `clickAndWait` in the IDE, and while the references stated clearly what each meant, when I export the test case to Python, it seems like both are doing the same thing here

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='pa-u_8298348-bd']/a/span[2]").click() #click and wait
driver.find_element_by_link_text("IMVironments").click() #click
```

Can someone tell me what is the difference here then?

Answer (score 4):

From [Selenium docs](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html):

> Many Actions can be called with the "AndWait" suffix, e.g.
>   "clickAndWait". This suffix tells Selenium that the action will cause
>   the browser to make a call to the server, and that Selenium should
>   wait for a new page to load.

Comment: And how do you get this with the python binding?

Answer (score 4):

2 years later, I know. But I was looking for the same answer and found it.

From the [Selenium Wiki](http://www.seleniumwiki.com/software-testing/selenium-the-%E2%80%9Candwait%E2%80%9D-commands/#more-29)

> The AndWait alternative is always used when the action causes the browser to navigate to another page or reload the present one.

In other words, Selenium's webdriver, when utilizing the Click() command, will inherently use the "AndWait" modifier if it recognizes a page load.

See also [Interface WebElement](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)

> void click()
>
> Click this element. If this causes a new page to load, this method will attempt to block until the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a python thing, but it appears you are only calling 'click' and are not calling 'clickAndWait'. I think this is what Trott is pointing out too.
With this said I have noticed that IE often requires AndWait a bit more often than Firefox or Chrome, which seem to deal with just click a bit better (due to speed?). You can also create your own 'wait' in Selenium, which is what I usually do in critical situations (as in you need to interact with a specific element so you 'wait' until it exists).

EDIT:
After your comment, I now understand what you are saying (was mildly confused about the 'clickandwait' comment :P). From what I can tell AndWait is not always available for the Python binding, I found that [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/selenium/selenium.selenium.html#selenium.selenium.selenium.click), but I'll admit it's not 100% clear as it suggests otherwise in other places. Perhaps this would be useful instead?

> wait_for_page_to_load(timeout)[source]
>
> Waits for a new page to load.
>
> You can use this command instead of the “AndWait” suffixes,
> “clickAndWait”, “selectAndWait”, “typeAndWait” etc. (which are only
> available in the JS API).

Placed this as an edit, because was too long for a comment, sorry!

Comment: actually what i meant was when exporting the IDE test case, clickAndWait and click actions from the IDE both translated into the same code in python, which was not what i was expecting..